# What is the difference? should vs would

Tags: modal-verbs

Seems both of these sentences are very similar:

> We **should** go fishing every day.
>
> We **would** go fishing every day.

Comment: In the most likely contexts for your texts, #1 is about what we *ought* to do / be doing (now or in the future), whereas #2 is about what we *habititually did* in the past (or what we would do if some hypothetical situation were to arise).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, We can use **would** as an alternative for **used to**. Am I right?

Comment: @Ganesh.R: Absolutely. But note that ***used to*** is far more likely in relaxed casual speech (***would*** is often a bit "poetic, fancy" in such contexts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We should go fishing every day

- You are telling a group of people, that you are part of, the following: you want you+them to go fishing every day.

  - You may be doing this because of some external reason, pressure, event, etc.  E.g., "We could win $20 in a fishing contest.  We should go fishing every day."
  - Your desire to make it happen might be that "external reason", and therefore *should* becomes a polite request, equivalent to the imperative "Let's go fishing every day."  It's also possible the external reason may need to be deduced from context or previous conversation.  E.g., "I just got out of the hospital.  We should not go to the park today. (Implying both that I'm still injured or recovering and that would interfere with whatever we are doing at the park.)"
  - The fact that "every day" is there makes it important, likely, you are suggesting to go fishing every day as opposed to less often.

> We would go fishing every day

- You are saying that in the past, every day you+them went fishing, in the sense that you planned it, then did it every day.  This is "will in the past."

or

- The context is providing a hidden "if", and the above is the "then" or main clause of a conditional.  E.g., if you said previously, "I wish we were independently wealthy."  Then you say the above.  You are then saying "if we were independently wealthy, then we would go fishing everyday."